# DataTemplate a ViewModel with a NON-Empty Constructor ?

Tags: wpf, constructor, viewmodel

how can I datatemplate a UserControl with a ViewModel with a NON-Empty constructor ?

```
public PersonViewModel(Person person)
{
   _person= person;
    // do some stuff                          
}
```

Binding this in Xaml will crash as the Ctor is not empty. But as I use parent/child relations with the ViewModels I have to pass the person object to the constructor of the ViewModel...

How do you cope with that situation?

Comment: Your ViewModels can have whatever constutors you like. It is the View (e.g. your UserControl) that should habe a default constructor. There must be something else wrong with your code. How about posting a more complete example (that uncludes the View+XAML)

Answer (score 1):

```
 var person = new Person();
 var viewModel = new PersonViewModel(person);

 var view = new EditPersonView(viewModel); // use overloaded constructor to inject DataContext
 // OR
 var view = new EditPersonView{ DataContext = viewModel };
```

If you really want to **instantiate** the view-model in XAML, then you need to expose a `public Person Person` property and stick with the parameterless constructor. Just do in the `Person` setter what you would have done in the constructor. Of course, now you have opened a can of worms because you'll also need to instantiate the `Person` in XAML with a parameterless constructor and soon things get very ugly…

Comment: as you say ugly... no solution in sight :/

Comment: @Lisa May I ask why you want to instantiate the view-model from the XAML? This is what makes things messy.

Comment: because I find this useful:................................ <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:CustomerViewModel}">
            <View:CustomerUserControl/>
        </DataTemplate>

Comment: I'm searching for a solution for the same problem, but no luck yet... Lisa is right as this viewmodel-first approach can be useful when for example you dynamically create tabs and each tab has a usercontrol as content.

Comment: I am still not sure why you need the view model in XAML for that. The data template above will "inherit" the data context of whatever control you assign the data template to. e.g. if you create a ContentControl and bind a PersonViewModel to the Content property and then assign this template to the ContentControl, then the CustomerUserControl will have the PersonViewModel as a DataContext.

Comment: I just realized how old this question is